# Eigenvectors in Julia vs Numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, julia, eigenvector

I'm currently working to diagonalize a 5000x5000 Hermitian matrix, and I find that when I use Julia's `eigen` function in the `LinearAlgebra` module, which produces both the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, I get different results for the eigenvectors compared to when I solve the problem using numpy's `np.linalg.eigh` function. I believe both of them use BLAS, but I'm not sure what else they may be using that is different.

Has anyone else experienced this/knows what is going on?

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the differences that you have observed.  In the meantime: (1) Eigenvectors are not unique--have you compared scalar multiples of the eigenvectors? (2) In the matrix `v` returned by `eigh`, the eigenvectors are in the *columns*, i.e. `v[:, 0]`, `v[:, 1]` etc. (This is a FOSC [frequently occurring source of confusion] here on SO.)

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.linalg.eigh(a, UPLO='L')` is a different algorithm. It assumes the matrix is symmetric and takes the lower triangular matrix (as a default) to more efficiently compute the decomposition.

The equivalent to Julia's `LinearAlgebra.eigen()` is `numpy.linalg.eig`. You should get the same result if you turn your matrix in Julia into a `Symmetric(A, uplo=:L)` matrix before feeding it into `LinearAlgebra.eigen()`.

Check out numpy's docs on [`eig`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html) and [`eigh`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html). Whilst Julia's standard LinearAlgebra capabilities are [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/). If you go down to the special matrices sections, it details what special methods it uses depending on the type of special matrix thanks to multiple dispatch.